# What's the input value for model in Arima.sim() in R?

Tags: r, arima

I am trying to understand meaning of the input value of the argument for model in Arima.sim()

The description was brief on the documentation [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/arima.sim.html)

I understand that you can simulate AR or MA by simply doing:

```
arima.sim(model = list(ar=0.9), n = 200
```

What I dont understand is the following:

```
arima.sim(model = list(order = c(0,1,0)), n = 100, mean = 1)
```

what do the three numbers in order c(0,1,0) represent? I only know that c(0,0,0) would give you a white noise and c(0,1,0) would give you a random walk. But I dont know why so. I have a feeling that this may have to do with statistical knowledge.

Appreciate if someone can point me to the right place to read. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Order stands for ARIMA model type. i. e `order=c(1,0,1)` will give you a ARMA(1,1) model,
`order=c(1,0,0)` will give you an AR(1) model, `order=c(0,0,1)` will give you an MA(1) and so on. ar, ma, and so on parameters specify the coefficients of the model.

Comment: thanks, i found it on wiki: p, d, and q are non-negative integers, p is the order (number of time lags) of the autoregressive model, d is the degree of differencing (the number of times the data have had past values subtracted), and q is the order of the moving-average model.

Comment: Glad you found it!

Answer (score 0):

`c(0,1,0)` produces white noise after differencing with lag = 1. So, integrating it back will give you random walk.